# Clear the contents of a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that combines sheets. I want the combined sheet to refresh when entries are added to the individual sheets.

I have formulas on other sheets that reference the combined sheet.

In the code for combining, the combined sheet is deleted if present and then added again. This messes up all the formula references. I would like to remove the part that deletes and re-adds the combined sheet, and instead clear the contents of the sheet then combine the data.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "CombinedReport" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CombinedReport").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "CombinedReport"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.name = "CombinedReport"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("UCDP", "UCD", "ULDD", "PE-WL", "eMortTri", "eMort", "EarlyCheck", "DU", "DO", "CDDS", "CFDS"))        
        Last = DestSh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row    

        'Fill in the range that you want to copy
        Set CopyRng = sh.UsedRange
        Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1, CopyRng.Columns.Count)


        'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
        'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you already have a question open, it's a little inconsiderate to post a duplicate without mentioning the existing post...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. I assume the formulae are on other sheets and refer to the destination sheet? This code does assume you have a "combinedreport" sheet to start with.

```
Sub x()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set destsh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CombinedReport")
destsh.UsedRange.ClearContents

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("UCDP", "UCD", "ULDD", "PE-WL", "eMortTri", "eMort", "EarlyCheck", "DU", "DO", "CDDS", "CFDS"))
    Last = destsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Fill in the range that you want to copy
    Set CopyRng = sh.UsedRange
    Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1, CopyRng.Columns.Count)

    'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
    If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > destsh.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
        GoTo ExitTheSub
    End If

    'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
    'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
    CopyRng.Copy
    With destsh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto destsh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
destsh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```